# Outputting an array of categories

Tags: php, laravel

On my page there is a choice of categories and, accordingly, the output of articles that are in the categories.

This is how it goes

```xml
<div class="blog-filter">
  <div class="blog-filter__item active" data-filter="all" value="All ({{ $allArticlesCount }})">
    All ({{ $allArticlesCount }})
  </div>
  @foreach ($categories as $category)
    <div class="blog-filter__item" data-filter=".category_{{ $category->id }}" value="{{ $category->title }} ({{ $category->articles_count }})">
      {{ $category->title }} ({{ $category->articles_count }})
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>

<div class="blog-list">
  @foreach($articles as $article)
    <div class="blog-article category_{{ $article->blog_category_id }}"
      <h2 class="blog-article__title">{{ $article->title }}</h2>
      <span>{{ date('d F Y', strtotime($article->published_at)) }}</span>
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

The problem is that I have one category `category_{{ $article->blog_category_id }}` for each article, and I recently made it possible to add multiple categories for an article. This is how it's done

```php
$article = Article::where('id', $request->article_id)->first();

$blog_categories_ids = json_decode($request->blog_categories_ids);

$article->blog_categories()->detach();

$blog_categories_ids = BlogCategory::whereIn('id', $blog_categories_ids)->pluck('id')->toArray();

$article->blog_categories()->attach($blog_categories_ids);

return response()->json([
    'message' => $blog_categories_ids
], 200);
```

And I also have a new many-to-many relationship and there is no `blog_category_id` field in the `article` now.

The question is, how can I display multiple categories in one article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php, the following lines

```php
$article->blog_categories()->detach();

$blog_categories_ids = BlogCategory::whereIn('id', $blog_categories_ids)->pluck('id')->toArray();

$article->blog_categories()->attach($blog_categories_ids);
```

can be replaced by just

```php
$article->blog_categories()->sync($blog_categories_ids);
```

---

To show all the categories, simply loop through them. Here's an example.

```xml
<h1>Article Title: {{ $article->title }}</h1>
<h2>Article Categories:</h2>
<ul>
  @foreach ($article->blog_categories as $category)
    <li>{{ $category->name }}</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

If you want to show every blog category's name. Maybe you can even use the collection's implode method to achieve it.

```xml
<h1>{{ $article->title }}<br><small>{{ $article->blog_categories->implode('name', ', ') }}</small></h1>
```

Comment: I need to get a list of ID categories, I tried to do this `category_{{ $article->blog_categories }}`, it works almost as it should, but it displays all the data from `blog_categories`, and I only need a list of IDs

Comment: in the output I should get something like `category_1, 2, 3`

Comment: and everything, sorry, I understand you just need to use `category_{{ $article->blog_categories->implode('id', ', ') }}`